# Xcode C++ window application

Tags: c++, xcode, cocoa, window

I'm studying at university. My classmates working in Visual Studio but I have Mac and I want to work in xCode. The programming language is C++.

I need to create a window application with a button and text label. When I click on the button the text in label must change.

Can you help me? How I can create window applications in Xcode in C++ and work with UI? Thank you.

Comment: Far too broad, consider following a [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/GettingStarted.html).

Comment: Consider starting with a [search for tutorials](https://www.google.be/search?q=create+gui+application+tutorial+xcode), pick one and follow the steps. (your question, as it is, is too broad; voted to close)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use QT on Mac instead. Applications created using XCode can only run on OSX and iOS. Also, to create UI in XCode you need to use Interface Builder in XCode. Google Interface builder tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

In general, GUI development is platform specific (Cocoa for OS X,.Net for Windows, GTK+ for Linux).

If your classes are doing GUI development, you should use whatever they are.  If they are using Windows, then you need to use whatever tools and libraries they are using.  If they aren't doing GUI development, then do whatever you like - but remember that GUI development is generally platform specific.

The exception to that generality is cross-platform suites like Qt (which isn't really completely cross-platform).  But, like Java, that portability comes at the cost of having a massive infrastructure and unique build system.  There's nothing wrong with wanting to learn and develop in it...just don't do it by ignoring your classes.

Qt does have a free open-source licensed version.  You can look into it more on the Qt-project site:https://qt-project.org